# In a while/for a long time

Tags: phrase, word-request

I know ''un bail'' can mean for a while/long time/in ages or ''un lustre'' but i think there is another.it sounds like ''balourette''(?). I have searched online but no luck.
Anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be thinking of the phrase ***belle lurette***.

*Belle lurette* is contracted from *belle heurette* (*heurette* is derived from *heure* but I've never heard the word being used outside this phrase). I don't think  *belle heurette* has survived and only *belle lurette* is used nowadays.

The word [*lurette*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lurette) is only used in this phrase.

- Il y a belle lurette.
- Voici belle lurette.

And it means "a long time ago".

They are set phrases :

- Ça fait un bail. / Il y a un bail.
- Ça fait des lustres. / Il y a des lustres. ([*lustres*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lustre) being used in the plural in this phrase).

They are colloquial.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! That is it exactly. very helpful.